# Remove Unicode characters from CSV files

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, unicode

The company I work for utilizes a MySQL database for most of its operations. Each week our vendors send us an update file in CSV format. We upload the file through our CRM software and it goes through and updates the records in our database. Ideally this works and everything finishes. It rarely is that simple.

Many times we will get a kickback from our system with the following message:

```
``Unicode Error exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with
message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of
collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and
(utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=' (SQL: select `id` from
`pool` where `first_name` in (Nathalia) and `last_name` = Rodr``
```

At this point I open the file in Excel, find the Unicode character causing the issue, in the case above, it is the next character after the last_name that starts with 'Rodr', remove it and try the upload again. I rinse and repeat until all the problem Unicode characters are removed and the upload completes.

Sometimes Excel's "Compatibility Report" is able to catch the problematic Unicode characters but usually they slip by.

I was hoping to find a solution to remove any unicode characters that would cause issues in a database table with a `latin1_swedish_ci` collation as I believe that is what is causing the issue with my uploads.

Comment: the `select` in the error implies you've already managed to load that csv into mysql, and are querying the table the data went into. why don't you just have mysql alter the charset of the relevant table/fields?

Comment: Your company had better not have any customers with non-ASCII characters in their name. If you really want to filter anyway, it's not difficult to write a small program, eg. using Python with the csv module.

Comment: For starters, don't you need quotes around `Nathalia`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. By "I was hoping to find a solution" do you mean you want us to recommend a site or reference? If so, that's off-topic. Do you mean you want us to write a solution? Again, that'd be off-topic as we need to see your effort. Please read "[ask]", including the links at the bottom, and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421. What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I'm sure you don't want to remove Unicode characters: Unicode is a universal catalogue that contains 120,000 characters, including English numbers and letters. What you really want is to convert between two encodings (UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1?) and either replace or strip characters that aren't supported by target encoding.